# Can't retrieve Header authorization by VueJs

Tags: vue.js, get, axios, header, authorization

I tried to get header authorization by VueJs but as u can see below couldn't retrieve the header authorization key.I tried with React and Postman it was working properly and retrieved the header authorization.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KULgg.png
the header authorization that I mentioned seems empty !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1qkH.png
this one tried by React and seems header auth. is OK

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmxrK.png
This one is output of the postman method

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue.
I dont need your help anymore.

If you want to see how I can fix you can contact me hear